# At its own discretion

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence

```
Company A can block this account at its discretion 
in case they think it harms them.
```

stylistically and grammatically correct? Also can the word

```
harms
```

used here?

Comment: It's not clear which part of the sentence you think might be grammatically incorrect. It all seems fine to me. Also, there is no such thing as "stylistically correct", as what it acceptable in one style may not be in another.

Answer (score 1):

'At its discretion' is right usage, but in the same sentence first you have used the pronoun 'it' for 'Company A' and later on you have used the pronoun 'they', which doesn't seem correct. People may argue that in this case 'they' is singular pronoun, however, I think that from consistency point of view it's not advisable to use two different pronouns for the same thing in one sentence.

The word 'harms' is perfectly OK, too, because 'Company A' is singular.

Comment: _Harms_ is ok because _the account_ (or _it_) is singular, not the company. The verb's number depends on the subject not the object.

Answer (score 1):

"At its discretion" is established legalese, but if you wish the entire sentence to be consistent, "can" should read "may". The sentence is also ambiguous. Is the only condition under which company A is entitled to close the account one in which it anticipates some harm to itself? If so, then you would need to say "only". *Harm* (the noun) is also established legalese and would be acceptable in such a sentence. You should not use the simple present tense, as it is a hypothetical scenario. Finally, the verb "think" is not typically found in such a sentence.  Since the account is not a sentient being, we would not normally use it as the subject of the verb *harm*.

**Company A may block this account at its discretion (only) if it anticipates some harm to itself if the account should remain open.**

You can also move "at its discretion" to make absolutely clear that the account has no say in the matter:

**Company A, at its discretion, may block this account (only) if it anticipates some harm to itself if the account should remain open.**

Finally, we'd normally refer to Company A in terms of its role (established at the beginning of the document) rather than its name, because in legalistic documents we want to avoid ambiguous pronouns. Let's call Company A the "Provider".

**Provider, at its discretion, may block this account (only) if Provider anticipates some harm to itself if the account should remain open.**